# $(this).css("width") not working on ancohor tags in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, popup, width

I'm using CSS selectors to generate custom pop-ups for a web templates - basically, some some the producers aren't comfortable with JS and I need an easy way for them to set pop-up sizes etc. I'm not really interested in the merits of this approach, but rather wish to understand why jquery seems to be unable to get the width and height as defined in the CSS for a anchor in Safari.

See: http://f1shw1ck.com/jquery_sandbox/csspops.html

The meat of my question:

For the selector `a.popup {width: 800px;height: 560px;}` and the anchor `<a href="http://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/apol/hd_apol.htm" class="popup">African Rock Art: Apollo 11 Cave Stone (c. 25,500 - 23,500 BCE)</a>` why are

```
if ($(this).css("width")) {   
windowParams.width = $(this).css("width");
}
if ($(this).css("height")) {   
windowParams.height = $(this).css("height");
}
```

both properties returning as zero in Safari?

onclick pop-up alert in other browsers: toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=800px,height=560px,top=20,left=240

alert in Safari: toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=0px,height=0px,top=20,left=640

Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andy is correct. There is a solution offered here:

[Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome/318796#318796)

Comment: Hmmm, aren't the height and width of anchors set on document load?

Comment: This is the key concept: "The root problem is that WebKit browsers (Safari and Chrome) load JavaScript and CSS information in parallel. Thus, JavaScript may execute before the styling effects of CSS have been computed, returning the wrong answer."

Comment: I added "if (jQuery.browser.safari && document.readyState != "complete"){
       //console.info('ready...');
       setTimeout( arguments.callee, 100 );
       return;
     }  "
which I thought would mean that the javascript would execute after the CSS was computed. But I'm still getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in Chrome either.

From [this link](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/size/) and [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126272/are-image-properties-part-of-the-dom-jquery-webkit-inconsistency-with-other-br), it looks like the reason is that Webkit browsers will report '0' or 'unknown' as the size until it is fully loaded, which may be too late.

As Micah notes, this is because Javascript and CSS are loaded in parallel, which means that the styling may not be fully applied by the time the scripts run.

Comment: Sorry, what image size? There aren't any images in my page... I'm dealing with anchors here... sorry, are you saying that anchors are loaded in the same way, because that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should've clarified. The issue is, as micah said, that the Javascript and CSS are loaded in parallel...image or anchor or otherwise.