# computing $(this).css(”width”) _correctly_ in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, cross-browser, width

Asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374914/this-csswidth-not-working-on-anchor-tags-in-safari) question earlier today, but I think I awarded a correct answer too early. I'm trying to figure out how to grab the css length and width of an anchor element with jquery in Safari. But I keep getting "0" returned, and I was told that this was because the javascript is firing before the css is rendered - a quirk of Webkit browsers.

Here is the original page: http://f1shw1ck.com/jquery_sandbox/csspops-orig.html

However, I wrote a little test, telling jquery to wait until everything is completely rendered before grabbing the css. http://f1shw1ck.com/jquery_sandbox/csspops.html

For selector

```
a.popup {
                width: 800px;
                height: 560px;
            }
```

and html

```
<a href="http://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/apol/hd_apol.htm" class="popup">African Rock Art: Apollo 11 Cave Stone (c. 25,500 - 23,500 BCE); Wonderwerk Cave Stones (c. 8000 BCE)</a>
```

wait until the page is completely, then get those dimensions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                if (jQuery.browser.safari && document.readyState != "complete"){
                    //console.info('ready...');
                    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 5000 );
                    return;
                  }
          alert($("a.popup").css("width"));
        });
```

Except "0" is still getting returned in Safari. Am I going about this the wrong way, or is there some other cause at play?

Thanks!

Comment: This is still driving me absolutely crazy - the only thing I can think of is somehow walking through each element and using `('selector').css('width', 800)` or whathaveyou to manually set the attributes...but that would be a terrible, horrible, no-good hack.

Comment: I'm losing sleep over this... not even sure I want to define popups this way, but I'm dying to figure a way to let users set popup meta data in CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colin is correct. The reason that it is returning 0 is because the anchors do not have an effective CSS width according to Safari because they are inline elements. This is probably a bug in jQuery for Safari.

Unrelated to the bug, setting the width of an anchor to define the width of the popup that it triggers does not seem like good practice to me. Why do you want to do this? Setting the CSS of an anchor that has nothing to do with the presentation of the anchor seems kind of backwards, just set it in the javascript to look for a.popup.large and set a certain width/height for the popup. Else, look for a.popup and set a different height and width.

Comment: Well, not my idea exactly, but it this project, there are folks using this this template to build sites who don't know javascript, just basic css.
We currently specify the browser elements with style names such as console and show-nav: <a class="popup console show-nav".... That is set in the JS, like you say. But we want users to be able to easily create their own styles that specify window sizes by name. Obviously, for purely linguistic reasons, using the "width" and "height" properties make the most sense, but, I dunno, "clip" or something could work. Just wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Tried adding `display: block` to a.popup?

That will force the link to be 800px wide, if you want to get its auto width then try

```
alert($("a.popup").width());
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand... the css selector won't actually be used for display, but to define the height and width of a pop-up. 

The question is, how can I get Safari and jquery to return the css defined values for my anchors' width and height? the other browsers work fine.

Comment: Perhaps `display: inline-block` would be better; since it allows for `width` to be defined, but retains the `inline` display type. (Albeit it works unreliably in IE6, though usually it's okay on normally-inline elements.)